# How to run Windows with GPU virtualization?

Tags: dual-boot, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, xen

A year ago I switched to Ubuntu for my primary OS, which has worked out just fine. Every now and then I want to play computer games and while using Wine often works, I can't get all of the games that I want to play working. I think the hardest problem to solve will be dealing with sharing of the GPU between systems. Now, I don't have any experience with virtualization - I've read about QEMU, KVM and Xen, but I have no clue how these fit together. Which hypervisor would enable me to run games in a virtualized OS? Can you recomend an article I can read to get a grasp of the current state of virtualization on Linux and in particular GPU virtualization?

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux SE! [Take a tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with our philosophy, and edit your question to provide more information, as well as make your question clearer; right now, you are asking two questions(although answering one asked in topic yourself). Asking only one question and making it clear makes it easier for others to provide useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Qemu-KVM for years and it's served me well.  I would study the  [Arch Linux Qemu wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU), the [Gentoo Linux Qemu wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU) and the 
[Qemu web site.](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)  That is the best *free-and-open* solution available for what you want to do.